Typescript types: Is there a better way to write function type signature in typescript which can restrict the following runtime error?
The following code snippet passes typescript checks
function foo(callback: (bool: boolean) => string) {
    callback(true);
}

type Interface1 = {
    func1: () => string;
};

const testFunction = (str: string = '') => str.toLowerCase();

const variable: Interface1 = { func1: testFunction };

// No typescript error, but will raise error on runtime
foo(variable.func1);

whereas the following statement throws a typescript error
foo(testFunction);

How could we catch this error at compile time?

If you'd like the function type in Interface1 at func1 to accept no arguments (or only undefined), then you can type it as (empty?: undefined) => string as demonstrated in this playground and the compiler will raise a diagnostic error as you expect. Does that address your question? If not, what did I miss?

It's a known intentional unsoundness in TS that the only way to avoid is not to alias twice like this, see the docs. TS doesn't have "exact parameter lists", see ms/TS#59096. There's essentially no way to prevent it, just avoid it by not using an intermediate () => string type. Does that fully address the q or am I (and the prev comment) missing something?

@jsejcksn Even variable2  in the code that you shared can't be passed to the function foo.
@jcalz  Considering the number of usage of the intermediate type in the current code base, its a bit tedious to remove the overall usage of this type.

^ @PrithivKrishna I’m confused… isn’t that what you want? If not, please [edit] the question to clarify your expectations.

I understand that this isn't what you want to hear, but it's just how TypeScript is. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/59096 as mentioned above.  Do you agree that it addresses the question, even if it doesn't answer it the way you like? Or do you think that it misses something about your question?

The problem is that you are kind of "lying" to the compiler:
const variable: Interface1 = { func1: testFunction }; // <-- here

You are basically telling the compiler that testFunction is of type typeof Interface1['func1']. The compiler is OK with this because the argument in testFunction (str: string = '') is optional and Interface1['func1'] (() => string) has no arguments.
If you use generics, the compiler will delay some of the type checks until the generic types are provided. This means that even if you "lie", no checks are performed at that time and later, when the checks actually take place the error will be detected.
I recommend using a generic type CallBack instead of bool: boolean) => string and () => string() => string:
type CallBack<TArgs, TTReturn> = (...args: TArgs[]) => TTReturn;

The update your code as follows:
function foo(
    callback: CallBack<boolean, string> // <-- Use CallBack<TArg1, TTReturn>
) {
    callback(true);
}

type Interface1 = {
    func1: CallBack<undefined, string>; // <-- Use CallBack<TArg1, TTReturn>
};

const testFunction = (str: string = '') => str.toLowerCase();

const variable: Interface1 = { func1: testFunction };

foo(variable.func1); // Error
foo(testFunction); // Error
foo((x: boolean) => '♥'); // OK

If you want more control over the types of the arguments you might need to defined more than one Callback type:
type UnaryCallBack<TArg1, TTReturn> =
    (arg1: TArg1) => TTReturn;

type BinaryCallBack<TArg1, TArg2, TTReturn> =
    (arg1: TArg1, arg2: TArg2) => TTReturn;
// ....

